# Is it possible to use BOOST_PARAM_TEST_CASE with automatic registration on boost::test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Is it possible to mix up the `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` and `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE` macros with the `BOOST_PARAM_TEST_CASE` in any way? I'm even interested in really messy ways of making this happen.

Having to build all of your test cases by hand seems really tedious. But the `BOOST_PARAM_TEST_CASE` mechanism is pretty darn useful, but only works if you have a test init function, which in turn requires you to have be using manual test case construction.

Is there any documentation on how to hook into the automated system yourself so you can provide your own tests that auto-register themselves?

I'm using boost 1.46 right now.

Comment: Nobody who knows much about the inner workings of `boost::test` is on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Boost version 1.59, this is being handled by [data-driven test cases](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_case_generation.html):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MainTest

#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

static const boost::array< int, 4 > DATA{ 1, 3, 4, 5 };

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE( Foo, DATA )
{
    BOOST_TEST( sample % 2 );
}
```

This functionality requires C++11 support from compiler and library, and does not work inside a `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE`.

If you have to support both old and new versions of Boost in your source, and / or pre-C++11 compilers, check out [And-y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38642890/60281).

Answer (score 12):

I wrote my own support for this since there really didn't seem to be any good support. This requires the C++11 `decltype` feature and the `::std::remove_const` and `::std::remove_reference` library methods to work.

The macro definitions are a modified versions of the `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE` and `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` macros.

You use this by declaring your function thus:

```
BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE(name, begin, end)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_LT(param, 5);  // The function will have an argument named 'param'.
}
```

Here is the header that defines the `BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE` macro:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp>
#include <boost/test/parameterized_test.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

#define BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, F, mbegin, mend )     \
struct test_name : public F {                                           \
   typedef ::std::remove_const< ::std::remove_reference< decltype(*(mbegin)) >::type>::type param_t; \
   void test_method(const param_t &);                                   \
};                                                                      \
                                                                        \
void BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name )(const test_name::param_t &param) \
{                                                                       \
    test_name t;                                                        \
    t.test_method(param);                                               \
}                                                                       \
                                                                        \
BOOST_AUTO_TU_REGISTRAR( test_name )(                                   \
    boost::unit_test::make_test_case(                                   \
       &BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name ), #test_name,                 \
       (mbegin), (mend)));                                              \
                                                                        \
void test_name::test_method(const param_t &param)                       \

// *******

#define BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, mbegin, mend )           \
   BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name,                            \
                                  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_FIXTURE,         \
                                  mbegin, mend)
```

Comment: I had issues with this code, complaining that couldn't find the right overload of `make_test_case`. I had to change `(mbegin), (mend)));` into `(mbegin), (mend)), boost::unit_test::decorator::collector::instance());`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution provided by @Omnifarious works works, but requires a C++11 compiler.

Adapting that solution for a C++03 compiler:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp>
#include <boost/test/parameterized_test.hpp>

#define BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, F, P, mbegin, mend )  \
struct test_name : public F                                             \
{                                                                       \
    typedef P param_t;                                                  \
    void test_method(const param_t &);                                  \
};                                                                      \
                                                                        \
void BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name )(const test_name::param_t &param) \
{                                                                       \
    test_name t;                                                        \
    t.test_method(param);                                               \
}                                                                       \
                                                                        \
BOOST_AUTO_TU_REGISTRAR( test_name )(                                   \
    boost::unit_test::make_test_case(                                   \
       &BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name ), #test_name,                 \
       (mbegin), (mend)));                                              \
                                                                        \
void test_name::test_method(const param_t &param)                       \

// *******

#define BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, param_type, mbegin, mend )           \
   BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name,                            \
                                  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_FIXTURE,         \
                                  param_type,                           \
                                  mbegin, mend)
```

This solution is slightly different is usage.  Since there is no `declspec` in C++03, the type of the parameter object cannot be automatically deduced.  We must pass it in as a parameter to `BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE`:

```
class FooTestParam                           
{    
public:                        
    std::string mS;    

    FooTestParam (int n)    
    {            
        std::stringstream ss;    
        ss << n;         
        mS = ss.str();                            
    }    
};         

FooTestParam fooParams [] =    
{         
    FooTestParam (42),    
    FooTestParam (314)    
};           

BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE (TestFoo, FooTestParam, fooParams, fooParams + 2)        
{                                                                                   
    const std::string testVal = param.mS;                                           
}                                                                                   

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE (TestAddressField)                                             
{                                                                                   
    const uint32_t raw = 0x0100007f;    // 127.0.0.1                                
    const uint8_t expected[4] = {127, 0, 0, 1};                                     
    const Mdi::AddressField& field = *reinterpret_cast <const Mdi::AddressField*> (&raw);    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)                                                  
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL (field[i], expected[i]);                                  
}
```

Comment: Omnifarious hasn't been seen in quite a while, so I ask you instead: Is there any reason why the base type `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_FIXTURE` is passed via macro parameter (that you are aware of), or is this a copypaste artifact from Omnifarious' C++11 solution? And is there a purpose to the `TestAddressField` test case in the example?

Comment: @DevSolar:  It's been some time since I've looked at this, and I don't recall all the technicals.  I could speculate...  Looks like it is a Boost-defined fixture that Boost uses to auto-register test cases.

Comment: Yes, `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_FIXTURE` is a Boost builtin. I was just wondering why both Omniborous and you passed that macro name from the outer macro (`BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE`) to the inner (`BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE`) by parameter, instead of hardcoding it in the inner one (like, could `BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE` be meaningfully called with a different base class parameter?). Nevermind. ;-)

Comment: `void BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER()` should have a `static` in front of it to avoid `-Wmissing-declarations` throwing a warning for each test case declared via this macro.

Comment: @DevSolar - I don't remember why I did it anymore. I suspect I made the macro by carefully modifying an existing macro that took the base as a parameter. The whole thing was a little magical to me, and so it's quite possible I engaged in some cargo-cult programming.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I only just returned to this Q&A because above solution died on me on a newer Boost. (Which is why I posted the new answer.) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily mix manual and automated test unit registration. Implement your own init function (like in example 20 on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/master-test-suite.html) page) and inside init function you can perform registration for parameterized test cases. Boost.Test will merge them both into single test tree.

Comment: I thought of this. But I have many separate source files each with their own tests, and the initialization function is expected to be a global function with a single name. I was hoping to be able to add new files with new parameterized tests without having to find the global init function and modifying it to add the tests.

Comment: Unfortunately parameterized test cases have to registered manually (I am working on a new feature to allow testing based on datasets which registers auto test cases). You can easily distribute registration mechanism by either using some kind of ffactory or simple through extern functions.

Comment: It's good to know that it can be distributed easily. But I'm not sure how a factory or simple extern functions can be used to accomplish this. I've actually dissected the auto-registration mechanism myself, and I'm thinking of writing a helper class that's designed to be instantiated as a static variable that will do the registration for me. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Since this answer (while helpful) really didn't do it for me, I wrote my own answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084038/is-it-possible-to-use-boost-param-test-case-with-automatic-registration-on-boost/8110228#8110228

Comment: @GennadiyRozental:  Any progress on this?

Answer (score 3):

Since Boost 1.59 internal details of realization was changed and Omnifarious's solution doesn't compile.

Reason ot that is changing signature of `boost::unit_test::make_test_case` function: now it take 2 additional args: `__FILE__, __LINE__`

Fixed solution:

```
#if BOOST_VERSION > 105800
#define MY_BOOST_TEST_ADD_ARGS __FILE__, __LINE__,
#define MY_BOOST_TEST_DEFAULT_DEC_COLLECTOR ,boost::unit_test::decorator::collector::instance()
#else
#define MY_BOOST_TEST_ADD_ARGS
#define MY_BOOST_TEST_DEFAULT_DEC_COLLECTOR
#endif

#define BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, F, mbegin, mend )     \
struct test_name : public F {                                           \
   typedef ::std::remove_const< ::std::remove_reference< decltype(*(mbegin)) >::type>::type param_t; \
   void test_method(const param_t &);                                   \
};                                                                      \
                                                                        \
void BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name )(const test_name::param_t &param) \
{                                                                       \
    test_name t;                                                        \
    t.test_method(param);                                               \
}                                                                       \
                                                                        \
BOOST_AUTO_TU_REGISTRAR( test_name )(                                   \
    boost::unit_test::make_test_case(                                   \
       &BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name ), #test_name,                 \
       MY_BOOST_TEST_ADD_ARGS                                           \
       (mbegin), (mend))                                                \
       MY_BOOST_TEST_DEFAULT_DEC_COLLECTOR);                            \
                                                                        \
void test_name::test_method(const param_t &param)                       \




#define BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, mbegin, mend )           \
   BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name,                            \
                                  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_FIXTURE,         \
                                  mbegin, mend)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  You just saved me endless hours of pain.

Comment: Later versions of Boost (sometime at 1.65 or earlier) apparently renamed `collector` to `collector_t`.

Answer (score 0):

I took Omnifarious' header file and modified it such that the parameter is passed to the constructor of the test fixture rather than to the test method. This requires the test fixture's constructor declaration to take a single argument with the parameter's type. I found this to be super handy--much thanks for the initial question and answer!

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp>
#include <boost/test/parameterized_test.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

#define BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, F, mbegin, mend )     \
struct test_name : public F {                                           \
    typedef ::std::remove_const< ::std::remove_reference< decltype(*(mbegin)) >::type>::type param_t; \
    test_name(const param_t &param) : F(param) {}                       \
    void test_method(void);                                             \
};                                                                      \
                                                                        \
void BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name )(const test_name::param_t &param)\
{                                                                       \
    test_name t(param);                                                 \
    t.test_method();                                                    \
}                                                                       \
                                                                        \
BOOST_AUTO_TU_REGISTRAR( test_name )(                                   \
    boost::unit_test::make_test_case(                                   \
       &BOOST_AUTO_TC_INVOKER( test_name ), #test_name,                 \
       (mbegin), (mend)));                                              \
                                                                        \
void test_name::test_method(void)                                       \

// *******

#define BOOST_AUTO_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name, mbegin, mend )           \
   BOOST_FIXTURE_PARAM_TEST_CASE( test_name,                            \
                                  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_FIXTURE,         \
                                  mbegin, mend)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the advantages of your solution over Omnifarious'?