# Boost Test: How to write parameterized test cases

Tags: unit-testing, boost, boost-test, parameterized-unit-test

I've got a boost test case. Most lines of this test case are executed regardless of the parameters. But there are parts which are executed based on the provided parameter. I want to avoid writing two separate test cases which are almost identical except in some minor parts. So I need to use something like the following approach to create parameterized test cases:

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(caseA, Fixture)
{
    TestFunction("parameterA");
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(caseB, Fixture)
{
    TestFunction("parameterB");
}

void TestFunction(string param)
{
    // ...
    // lots of common checks regardless of parameters
    // ...
    if(param == "parameterA")
        BOOST_CHECK(...);
    else if(param == "parameterB")
        BOOST_CHECK(...);
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve my goal in a more convenient way? I could find [BOOST_PARAM_CLASS_TEST_CASE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/utf/components/test_case/param_class_tc.html) macro but I am not sure if it's relevant in this case.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8110228/1252091) may be useful to you(I have not tested the code).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use BOOST\_PARAM\_TEST\_CASE with automatic registration on boost::test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084038/is-it-possible-to-use-boost-param-test-case-with-automatic-registration-on-boost)

Answer (score 3):

Check out BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE which does exactly what you need. New in boost 1.62.

(This question is a little old, but was the first hit when I searched for how to do this)

Answer (score 1):

No Boost support AFAIK, so I do this:

```
void test_function(parameters...)
{
    <test code>
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test01) {
    test_function(parameters for case #1)
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test02) {
    test_function(parameters for case #2)
}
```

You can do it with templates if you like them:

```
template<int I, bool B>
void test_function()
{
    for(int i=0; i<I; i++)
        if (B) BOOST_REQUIRE(i<10);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test01) {
    test_function<10, true>();
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test02) {
    test_function<20, false>();
}
```